# contribute to add/remove in eclipse servers publish wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

Can I add an error message/ warning in eclipse add and remove wizard?

If I select a project in "add and remove" wizard, I should be able to display a warning or error message in the the wizard.

Any ways to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add validation message to Add/Remove wizard by implementing this method:

```
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerDelegate.canModifyModules(IModule[], IModule[])
```

You can return validation message as `IStatus` object.